# c++ get user name in a class and pass it to a function

Tags: c++, open-source

O.K. so what I'm trying to do is make a class named greeter, have it get the current username then pass it to a funtion that says "Hello (username)".

What I have so far is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class greet
    {
    public:

    void hello(string name)
    {
    cout << "Hello, " + name + "!" << endl;
    }
    };

  int main()
      {
      greet user;
      user.hello(name);
      return 0;
      }
```

"name" was origionally going to be passed directly to the function as an argument coming from user input but

```
user.hello()
```

won't accept the variable "name" and I would rather the program get the username on it's own anyway. So my question is how can I get C++ to get the username on it's own and pass it from a variable to user.hello()

Comment: What platform are you targetting? Different OSes implement users differently, and provide different APIs to query user information. There is nothing in C++ itself, or the STL, to handle this for you.

Comment: Preferabley a cross-platform solution but my system is Linux so if it can't be "one size fits all" then for Linux.

Comment: I'ts not a practical project just to help me figure out classes

Comment: Don't change your question title to "SOLVED". Accept an answer if it helped or post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) to get the name of the current user. The environment variable for Linux is `"USER"`. The environment variable for Windows is `"USERNAME"`.

On Linux, the following should work.

```
int main()
{
   greet user;
   char const* name = std::getenv("USER");

   // Windows
   // char const* name = std::getenv("USERNAME");

   user.hello(name);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Josh, you need to add `#include <cstdlib>` to your file.

Comment: thanks builder (IDE) is not giving any more errors but gcc says:                                                                                      In function 'int main()': error: no matching function for call to 'greet::hello(const char*&)'
       user.hello(name);
                      ^
 note: candidate: void greet::hello()
       void hello()
            ^~~~~
  candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

Comment: Take a look the sample program at http://ideone.com/Y48u7X. It does not run there since the environment variable `"USER"` is not defined. But it builds just fine.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I had when I got that error (I indent differently). I tried something else but that threw so many errors so I copy/pasted that example and it's suggesting I rename "name" to "rename"

Comment: O.K. renamed it to rename and compiles and runs fine

Comment: @Josh, use of `rename` as a variable does not sound good. There is function in the standard library by that name.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class greet
{
   public:

      void hello(string user)
      {
         cout << "Hello, " + user + "!" << endl;
      }
};

int main()
{
   greet user;
   char const* USER = std::getenv("USER");
   user.hello(USER);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class greet {
private:
    string userName() const {
        static string user = getenv(
            #ifdef WIN32
            "USERNAME"
            #else
            "USER"
            #endif
        );
        return user;
    }

public:
    void hello() {
        cout << "Hello, " + userName() << "!" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    greet user;
    user.hello();
    return 0; 
}
```